# How to say "with what we have learnt"?

Tags: sentence-structure

I want to write the following sentence in german:

"It is a direct contradiction with what we have learned."

But then I realize, the phrase "with what we have learned" can't be translated simply as "mit was wir gelernt haben", because preposition in german can only with noun, right? A quick search on context.reverso seems to confirm my suspicion.

Based on my previous knowledge of german, the correct translation seems to be:

"Es ist ein direkter Widerspruch damit, was wir gelernt haben."

But it is unwiedly and doesn't sound quite right to me. Maybe I'm just too used with the English construct, and germans actually say that?

Am I right?

Comment: Are you sure the best preposition in English would be "with", and not "to"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Den englischen Satz

> It is a direct contradiction with what we have learned.

würde man in gutem Deutsch wiedergeben als

> Das widerspricht dem, was wir gelernt haben.
>
> Das widerspricht dem, was wir gelernt haben, direkt.

Etwas bürokratischer würde man sich mit einer Nominalkonstruktion ausdrücken:

> Das steht im Widerspruch zu dem, was wir gelernt haben.
>
> Das steht in direktem Widerspruch zu dem, was wir gelernt haben.
>
> Das steht in direktem Widerspruch zum Gelernten.

Allgemein sind aber Sätze, in denen Verben das Sagen haben, jenen, in denen Nomen dominieren, vorzuziehen. Es kommt natürlich immer auf den Kontext und die Textsorte an. Und auch der Satzrhythmus kann manchmal sein Gewicht in die Schale werfen.

Comment: *mettre qc dans la balance* ist auf deutsch: *etw. in die **Waag**schale werfen.* Jede*r kann erkennen, woher deine Interferenzen kommen. :-)) Cheers!

Answer (score -4):

I think that it would also be considered correct to use ,womit. That word was designed for sentences like this. So for that part which you are talking about you could use, "womit wir gelernt." or "womit wir gelernt haben". You could also use lernten instead gelernt.

Comment: Das Ergebis Ihres Vorschlags wäre: „Es ist ein direkter Widerspruch damit, *womit wir lernten*.“ Das ergibt weder inhaltlich noch grammatisch irgendeinen Sinn.